# Angular 7 IIS rewrite rule

Tags: angular, iis, angular7

I am using Angular 7 alongside with IIS server. I would like to enable deep linking without enabling hash location strategy

```
(RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true}))
```

My app path consists of a domain and a subdomain:

http://www.example.com/mysubdomain/

index.html:

```
<base href="/mysubdomain/" />
```

I have added also into Web.config file of Visual Studio the following rewrite rule:

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="contacts" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="/mysubdomain/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" />                    
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

"contacts" is a routing path declared in my routing module. The above configuration works if I type 'http://www.example.com/mysubdomain/contacts' in the browswer and hit enter, but it fails (404.0 - Not Found) when I replace "contacts" with anything else. I have tried to replace the value of url attribute with ".*" but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Since your app path is : http://www.example.com/mysubdomain/

just set following changes for the base url after building your project.

// in **index.html**

```
   <base href="./" />
```

//The base tag tells our Angular application where it will be deployed.
I had similiar issue and this has fixed for me.Let me know if any issues!